# Sharing a PC Internet to a Android phone via Bluetooth

Tags: internet, android, bluetooth

My PC has an Internet connection. My Android phone does not have Internet connection. My PC has a Bluetooth adapter. My Android phone supports Bluetooth.

How I can share my PC Internet connection with my Android phone via Bluetooth?

Comment: See also: [Share internet connection from windows to android via bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/857066)

Answer (score 1):

You can download third-party software like mHotspot and make your Ethernet connection a hotspot. Or you can download other software like PDANet for Windows and PDANet+ for Windows and connect over USB, or Bluetooth. But you will need to pay for PDANet and PDANet+.

Comment: I installed mHotspot but it can't even startup. Also, it modify my browser settings and install lots of rubbish-software on my PC. Not only that, during the installation, it keep open my web browser and attempt to access a website. May I know if you have other better solution?

Comment: Well if mHotspot doesn't start up, the help section on mHotspot has links for the fix, and if that doesn't work, you can always torrent PDANet+ and PDANet, and if it installs rubbish, check your add-on settings.

Comment: If you are reading this in 2016, this no longer works for android v5 and above