# net connect with android and win8.1 via bluetooth

Tags: windows-8.1, android

I want to connect internet from my pc to my android phone. I am using windows 8.1. I have tried this [Sharing a PC Internet to a Android phone via Bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/782815/sharing-a-pc-internet-to-a-android-phone-via-bluetooth). but its not working.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you tried and in which way it failed? “Doesn’t work” is not an error description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier and faster to share internet with wifi. Just google "windows 8 virtual wifi", one of the software is http://www.virtualwifirouter.com/ although I didn't use it myself.